# Cubic surface with an A5 singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How do you see that the cubic surface given by
$WXZ+Y^2Z+X^3=0$
has an $A_5$ singularity at $[W:X:Y:Z]=[1:0:0:0]$? (Reference: Class XIX https://www.singsurf.org/parade/Cubics.php)

I was thinking one could either resolve it or compute the colength of the ideal generated by the partials (milnor number), but I wondered if there was a way that provided more insight (similar to how an $A_n$ curve singularity can be detected using curvilinear schemes or a way to put it into the normal form $x^2+y^2+z^6$ for an $A_5$ surface singularity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Projection from this singular point gives a rational map from the cubic surface to $\mathbb{P}^2$. Its inverse is the map 
$$
\mathbb{P}^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3,\qquad
(x:y:z) \mapsto \left(- \frac{y^2z + x^3}{xz} : x : y : z \right).
$$
Thus, it blows up the subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^2$ defined by equations
$$
xz = y^2z + x^3 = 0
$$
and then takes the anticanonical image of the blowup.

It is easy to trace that there will be six (-2) curves on the blowup: one (out of two) exceptional divisor over the point $(0:0:1)$ and a chain of length 5 consisting of strict transforms of lines $x = 0$ and $z = 0$ and three (out of four) exceptional divisors over the point $(0:1:0)$. The first will give an $A_1$ singularity (at point $(0:0:0:1)$) and the second will give the $A_5$ singularity at point $(1:0:0:0)$.

Comment: Dear Sasha, thanks for your answer. I did some explicit computation to understand your last paragraph: The rational map $f:(x:y:z)\mapsto (-(y^2z+x^3)/xz:x:y:z)$ blows up two non-reduced points at $[0:1:0]$ and $[0:0:1]$ determined by the ideals $(xz,z+x^3)$ and $(x,y^2+x^3)$ in affine coordinates. The blowup of the first ideal has equation $xz=\alpha(z+x^3)$ with an $A_3$ singularity at the origin. The blowup of the second ideal has equation $x\beta=y^2+x^3$ with an $A_1$ singularity at the origin. These are the only two singularities on the graph closure $\overline{\Gamma(f)}$ of $f$...

Comment: (continued) defined on $U=\mathbb P^2\setminus [0:1,0],[0,0,1]$ with closure taken in $\mathbb P^2\times \mathbb P^3$. When you say "six (-2) curves", did you further resolved the singularity on the graph closure? Also, my interpretation is that the image of $\overline{\Gamma(f)}$ under the second projection $\pi_2$ is the original singular cubic surface, and via $\pi_2$, the $A_3$ and $A_1$ singularities on $\overline{\Gamma(f)}$ is sent to $A_5$ and $A_1$ on the cubic surface. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @AGlearner: I think this is correct.

Comment: Thank you, Sasha. It took me a while to understand this completely. I'm wondering if the following understanding of mine looks correct to you? If $X$ is a cubic surface with ADE singularities, and let $f:X'\to X$ be the minimal resolution, then (1) $f$ factors through $Y$, which is the variety as blowup along the length 6 scheme in $\mathbb P^2$ with respect to a singularity $p\in X$ as you described. (2) $g:Y\to X$ is blowdown of the proper transform of the conic determined by the length 6 scheme.

Comment: (3) $g$ sends a less singular (probably smooth) point $q\in Y$ to $p$, and $g$ preserves the type of other singularities on $Y$. Thank you again for your answer and help!

Comment: @AGlearner: I would rather say that the minimal resolution $X'$ of $X$ is a weak del Pezzo surface of degree 3, hence it is an iterated 6-step blowup of the plane. Note that representation of iterated blowups as blowups of ideals is very non-trivial. For instance, the simplest 2-step blowup (blowup a point and then blowup a point on the exceptional curve) is equivalent to blowing up the ideal $(x^2,y)\cdot(x,y) = (x^3,xy,y^2)$ which has length 4.

Comment: Dear Sasha, thanks for your reply. I think I understand that the minimal resolution $X'$ of $X$ should correspond to blow-up 6 bubble points in $\mathbb P^2$ as described in Dolgachev's Classical Algebraic Geometry, p.497, and the resolution $X'\to X$ is given by anticanonical map $|K_{X'}|$ which blows down all of the $(-2)$-curves. However, motivated by your answer, I'm wondering if there is any relationship with the blowup of length 6 scheme? In other words, if we fix a singularity $p\in X$, and suppose $p=[1,0,0,0]$ then the equation of $X$ can be written as $xQ(y,z,w)+C(y,z,w)=0$.

Comment: The intersection of the quadric and the cubic cone $Q=C=0$ defines a length 6 scheme. If we blow up the length 6 scheme on $\mathbb P^2$ and denoted as $Y$, then what should be the relationship between $Y$ and $X'$ and $X$? Thank you very much!

Comment: @AGlearner: The blowup $Y$ of the plane at $Q = C = 0$ is isomorphic to the blowup of $X$ at $p$ (the morphism $Y \to X$ contracts the strict transform of the conic $Q = 0$). I guess the minimal resolution $X'$ of $X$ is at the same time the minimal resolution of $Y$.

Comment: Dear Sasha, this makes a lot more sense to me, and it is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for your explanation! I guess what previously confuse me is that the planar models for $X'$ and $Y$ are different. In other words, the (-2) curves on $X'$ are in the chains of bubbles supported over points on $\mathbb P^2$ , but for $Y$, the (-2) curve(s) are proper transform of a conic on $\mathbb P^2$. I guess one need to do some transformation to see that the $(-2)$ curve(s) on $Y$ can be placed on the bubbles, therefore the minimal resolution $X'\to Y$ is to contract other (-2) curves